# Ubuntu 14.04 systray icons open menu on left click

Tags: 14.04, system-tray

In Ubuntu 14.04, when left clicking systray icons like Google Hangouts or Chromium, the context menu opens. This also happens when right clicking. For some icons this is logical (volume, time, etc... don't have an application behind it) but Hangouts opens a menu with "Hangouts" to open the Hangouts app. Pretty retarded...

In short, does anyone know how to make application systray icons open their applications (or first menu item) when left-clicking?

Comment: I'm also interested in this feature

Comment: I switched to Linux Mint. In Mint the left and right clicks are switched compared to Ubuntu, as they should be. Since Mint is based on Ubuntu, it should be possible.